# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Salesforce's [first moderator election](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and your newly elected moderators are:

[image: metadaddy] [image: LaceySnr] [image: Samuel De Rycke]

They'll be taking over for [the moderators pro tempore](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) shortly — please thank them *all* for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4905068407029760/0).

Comment: Congratulations everyone!

Comment: Thank you everyone for voting in this election .Huge congrats to our new moderators .This community has been amazing and just received mail from stackexchange thanking for all contribution.I have no words .Thanks to this great community.People having amazing here and it has been great journey and this will be endless journey I believe for me .I have learned so much here that I have grown from kid to adult with this community.From a simple developer to advanced developer and almost close to technical architect .Still long way to go and would love keep going .Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Congrats to the mighty 3 .. and good luck :-)

Comment: Congratulations everyone!

Comment: Congrats Matt & Pat (that rhymes good as well)! I look forward to making SFSE even more awesome working with the moderators team and other contributors!

Comment: Congrats everyone!!!

Answer (score 12):

I believe most has already been said in the nomination and questionaire. Congrats to Metadaddy & LaceySnr and thank you, all of you, for the trust you give us.

Comment: Congrats @samuel-de-rycke

Comment: Congrats @Samuel Well deserved and I'm sure you'll do a great job!

Answer (score 9):

First, congrats to  [@LaceySnr](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/78/laceysnr) and [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) for being "re-elected". I think that speaks volumes about what the community thinks of the the job the two of you have done in leading this forum from being just an idea to becoming a reality with the help of [@Saariko](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/260/saariko). Also, a big congrats to to [@SamuelDeRycke](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/119/samuel-de-rycke) for earning a spot on the leadership team. As I recall, nearly everyone one of the candidates said they thought Samuel was the most deserving of the other candidates. It appears those who voted agreed with them (29% of members eligible to vote, cast votes in the election).

Congrats to all three of you and kudos to the others who *"tossed their hats in the ring"* and chose to put themselves out there to run against these fine candidates. In my view, you were all "winners" as there's much to be done here regardless of whether one has a black diamond beside their name or not.

I hope everyone will continue to get behind our new team of moderators as we leave the beta stage;  growing and expanding as our reputation for excellence in meeting the needs of SF Developers spreads.

Comment: I couldn't said/written it better!!  Congrats, and well done.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to seeing the site grow over the next year, just wish we still had the same level of stats we had at beta! :)

Comment: @LaceySnr No worries we are committed for this community and will help our best to get better stats .Thanks and congrats again .

Comment: Ah I phrased that badly! I meant visibility of the stats :) The Area51 stats and site stats got frozen/removed when it went live!

Comment: @LaceySnr Oh i see now .Yes scores would have kept us going :)